# tkinter: Best way to tag an arbitrary widget for retrieval

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

While building my own widgets based on the stock ones, I've been adding a "name" field to every widget class of mine for easier access later, like:

```
class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, name, *args, *kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, *kwargs)
        self.name = name
```

After setting up the entire window layout, I could do something like:

`mywidget = allWidgets['myWidgetName']`

But I couldn't help but wonder if there is a better approach by using a widget's built-in attributes, without adding a new tag. I know that `winfo_children（）` helps traverse the widget tree, but I do need random access.

Comment: Um... Do you mean hashing a string or hashing a `widget`? In your question, I see you are hashing a string?

Comment: @Sraw I edited my question and title for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that all widgets already accept a `name` parameter? The string representation of the widget is its name and the names of its ancestors, separated by periods.

Comment: @BryanOakley hmm, no, not really. When I look at the official doc like the Button one: https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html , `name` is not part of the option list. Shall I do it through `.configure()`?

Comment: No, you can only do it when you create the widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley got it. It's unfortunate that this piece of info is not easy to find in the official doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @BryanOakley 's tip, I finally discovered that all Tkinter widgets have a `._name` attribute, whose default value is `!<classname>`, all lowercase even if the classname uses mixed cases.

I could then assign any name to `._name` after instantiating my widget class.
It's understandable that this detail falls out of the official doc because this is not part of the public interface, but knowing this instantly saved memory for my own work.

However, I guess that it'd be my own responsibility to maintain the uniqueness of widget names if I started playing around with it.

I have to thank Bryan a million for his resourcefulness when it comes to Tkinter.